# How can I set an APNS Collapse ID using Parse Server Notifications?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

There are certain options that APNS allows you to set within the HTTP header when delivering notifications to iOS devices. The one I am interested in is `apns-collapse-id`, but it is only accessible within the HTTP header when sending a request to APNS. Is there any way to set this value when using Parse Server, for instance through the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been implemented in the latest versions.

[Parse Server 2.0.0](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-push-adapter/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2017-03-14)